# How do I store information of a list permanently which I can then edit?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I wanted to make a simple mock schedule entry for customers with appointments. Here is my initial code:

```
data = [input("Name: "),input("Appointment: "), input("Reason: ")]
for item in enumerate(data):
    print(item[0], item[1])
print(data[0:])
```

I made the data needed into a list where I can input new appointments for people. Name, Appointment date (ex July 27th), and Reason. It runs fine and populates the list with the inputs and shows the index as well, but how do I store this information in a permanent list or table and then add or detract from that list or table of the schedule? Would appreciate resources for concepts as well, thank you.

Comment: lists in python and every language are not permanent, you will need to store them in an external way such as a JSON file, and then reload them when you want to use/read them

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()` to add your list to a list of all appointments.

```
appointments = []
while True:
    data = [input("Name: "),input("Appointment: "), input("Reason: ")]
    appointments.append(data)
    resp = input("Do you have more appointments to enter? (y/n)")
    if resp != 'y':
        break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense with the while loop.